# How to display video thumbnails in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am trying to show a thumbnail for my video. I store my video in my directory, but I get an error in my log cat `NO THUMB NAIL`. Can anyone  help me how to solve this? Another thing is that when I run my app on a MOTO G device it shows an image name, but when I tested the same app on a nexus device it shows no files here.

```
public class Vedigridview extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/pawan_app");

    String[] fileList = null;
    GridView gridView;
    String FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/pawan_app";
    String MiME_TYPE = "video/mp4";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vedigridview);

        updateSongList();
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        if (fileList != null) {
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, fileList));
        }
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                                .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String videoFilePath = FILE_PATH + fileList[position];
                System.out
                        .println("******************************videoFilePath****************"
                                + videoFilePath);

                System.out
                        .println("******************************MiME_TYPE****************"
                                + MiME_TYPE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                File newFile = new File(videoFilePath);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), MiME_TYPE);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    public void updateSongList() {
        File videoFiles = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        Log.d("*********Value of videoFiles******", videoFiles.toString());

        if (videoFiles.isDirectory()) {
            fileList = videoFiles.list();
        }
        if (fileList == null) {
            System.out.println("File doesnot exit");
            Toast.makeText(this, "There is no file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("fileList****************" + fileList);
            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                Log.e("Video:" + i + " File name", fileList[i]);

            }
        }

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        private final String[] VideoValues;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] VideoValues) {
            this.context = context;
            this.VideoValues = VideoValues;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.out.println("***********IngetView************");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);

                // get layout from gridlayout.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlayut, null);

                // set value into textview
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
                textView.setText(fileList[position]);
                System.out.println("value of fileList[position]" + fileList[0]);
                // set image
                ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

                Bitmap bmThumbnail;

                System.out
                        .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> file path>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
                                + fileList[position]);

                bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(FILE_PATH
                                + fileList[position],
                        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);



                if (bmThumbnail != null) {
                    System.out
                            .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> THUMB NAIL>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                    imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>NO THUMB NAIL>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                }

            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // return 0;
            return VideoValues.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Here my error in my logcat:

```
01-31 18:06:41.997 3776-3776/com.foldervedoi.videofolder I/System.out: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>NO THUMB NAIL>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: As a side note, don't use `System.out.println` for debugging Android apps - this is what `Log.d`, `Log.i` and `Log.e` are for.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks really bad. First of all switch to Log.d to log debug messages. Dont use System.out in Android.

Coming back to the problem:

```
 bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(FILE_PATH
                            + fileList[position],
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

I think that in this case you simply miss path element separator while concatenating FILE_PATH + fileList[position]. This is another example of bad code. Try to use java.io.File abstraction to operate on files. For instance:

```
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(new File(fileList[position], new File(FILE_PATH)).getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Note that while calling new File(fileName, parentDirectory) you can easily handle separators problem and the code is easier to read.